# how to get next element in j query?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make jQuery do this:

When I click the button, it chooses the `next()` element and clones it. If I click the button again, it chooses next element of next element and clones it, and so on...

LONG STORY SHORT ... I click one time it clones "2" I click again it clones "3" and so on ...

What's going wrong and how can I achieve that?

```js
var x = $(".show");
$(".button").click(function() {
  $(".first").next().clone(true, true).appendTo(x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button class="button">CLICK ME</button>
  <ul style="position:relative; top:100px;">
    <div class="test">
      <div class=first>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="show"></div>
```

Comment: Where's `.show`? BTW  `<li>` is would make more sense in `<ul>` rather than `<div>`. If you don't want those goofy looking bullets, add `list-style:none` to `<ul>` CSS.

Comment: Also you should add the end tag: `</ul>` to `<ul>` to close it.

Comment: I just got the basic style so that readers don't get confused by much code ... keeping it simple

Comment: That's admirable, but note that `<ul>` elements can *only* contain "zero or more `<li>` elements" and that "both the starting and ending tag are mandatory". -- [`<ul>` @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```js
var x = $(".show");
var count = 0;

$(".button").click(function() {

  var element = $(".first");
  count++;

  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    element = $(element).next();
  }

  $(element).clone(true, true).appendTo(x);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <button class="button">CLICK ME</button>
  <ul>
    <div class="test">
      <div class=first>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="show"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This Demo is a reusable function (just remember to declare the interval (`var i = 0`) outside of the function.) Since you didn't mention whether you wanted to clone past the number of given nodes I added a confirmation once you reach that limit.

### Demo

```js
var i = 0;

$(".button").on('click', function() {
  dupeNode('.hide li', '.show');
});


function dupeNode(selector, TO) {
  if (i > $(selector).length - 1) {
    return msg.call(this);
  }
  $(selector).eq(i).clone(true, true).appendTo($(TO));
  i++;
}

function msg() {
  var m = confirm(`
Last item was already cloned.
[OK] to at the beginning or
[Cancel] to quit.`);
  var x = m ? i = 0 : false;
  return x;
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-table;
}

li::after {
  content: "\2c\a0";
}

.show {
  visibility: visible
}

.hide {
  visibility: hidden
}
```

```html
<main class="container">
  <button class="button">CLICK ME</button>
  <ul class='show'></ul>

  <ul class="hide">
    <li class=first>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>

</main>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```